# Initiating a template with some information filled in

Tags: docusignapi

We have doucusign template created. I can use REST API to initiate the template. But the form elements are quite complicated for end user to understand so we want to fill in half of the information before sending the template to client.

So far whatever I have seen is I can add roles to to Template but haven't found anything related to filling the values in template. How to achieve that?

Comment: Are you using the DocuSign SDKs or are you sending raw (RESTful) API requests?  And if using SDKs which language?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to *composite* the server-stored template with the field values that your integration is supplying.

Do this with the CompositeTemplates feature of the Envelopers::Create method.

[Docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Rules%20for%20CompositeTemplate%20Usage.htm)

Also, search StackOverflow for answers that discuss CompositeTemplates.